# "capacidades de comunicación y expresión tanto escritas como verbales" o "capacidades de comunicación y expresión tanto escrita como verbal"?

Tags: adjetivos, plurales, concordancia-gramatical

Es correcta esta frase,
*Persona competente en el uso de ordenador y con excelentes capacidades de comunicación y expresión tanto **escritas** como **verbales**.*

o mejor

*Persona competente en el uso de ordenador y con excelentes capacidades de comunicación y expresión tanto **escrita** como **verbal**.*

Creo que la segunda frase es correcta pero no estoy seguro de eso.

*Persona competente en el uso de ordenador y con excelente capacidad de comunicación tanto **escrita** como **verbal**.*

no la dudaría que es la frase correcta pero con

*[...]capacidades de comunicación y expresión tanto escrita como verbal.*

tengo mis dudas porque son los dos capacidades, **comunicación** y **expresión**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la frase en cuestión:

"Persona competente en el uso de ordenador y con excelentes capacidades de comunicación y expresión tanto escrita como verbal".

contiene un error clave, que es considerar que lo escrito no es verbal (ver por ejemplo [este artículo](https://www.significados.com/comunicacion-verbal/)). La frase debiera ser:

"Persona competente en el uso de ordenador y con excelentes capacidades de comunicación y expresión tanto escrita como **oral**".

Dicho esto, la frase es un claro caso de sustantivos coordinados que se conciben como una unidad, tal como reza el artículo del DPD citado por @tac:

> No obstante, cuando los sustantivos coordinados se conciben como una unidad, de la que cada uno de ellos designa un aspecto parcial, el adjetivo puede concordar en género y número con el más próximo: «La gente de origen y habla francesa predomina en la provincia de Quebec» (Tiempo [Col.] 1.7.98).

Claramente, las capacidades no son escritas u orales--la comunicación y la expresión lo son. Las capacidades pueden ser mentales, físicas, emocionales. En este caso, estamos hablando de capacidades mentales.

Por lo tanto, dado que "comunicación" y "expresión" forman un todo, lo más natural sería utilizar los adjetivos en singular:

"Persona competente en el uso de ordenador y con **excelentes capacidades de comunicación y expresión tanto escrita como oral**".

Comment: Uf, que contradictorio. ¿Cómo es eso de que 'forman un todo'? O sea, yo veo gramaticalmente dos sustantivos y dos adjetivos. Y si queremos que se entienda sin ambiguedades que los dos adjetivos afectan a cada sustantivo a la vez ¿no deberían estar en plural?

Comment: @tac Tanto es así que sustantivos coordinados que forman una unidad de sentido pueden tener un verbo en singular. Observa estos ejemplos en http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro/ARCHIVO-Foro/Concordancia%20del%20verbo%20con%20el%20sujeto.htm: Varios sustantivos en singular unidos por y, y considerados por el hablante como una unidad, llevan verbo en singular:

La compra y venta de estos objetos está prohibida.

Mi heroísmo y firmeza me hacía superior a todas las mujeres.

Answer (score 1):

La segunda opción es la correcta:

"*Persona competente en el uso de ordenador y con excelentes capacidades de comunicación y expresión tanto escrita como verbal*".

En este caso, "**escrita" y "verbal**" son adjetivos que se refieren a "*comunicación y "expresión*", y como tales deben concordar en género y número con el sustantivo que modifican. Como "*comunicación y expresión*" son dos sustantivos femeninos, los adjetivos que los modifican deben estar en femenino y en singular, por lo que la forma correcta es "**escrita**" y "**verbal**" y no "*escritas*" ni "*verbales*".

Comment: Gracias. Agregué un poco a mi pregunta en respuesta a tu respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

No estoy para nada de acuerdo con las demás respuestas:

> Cuando un adjetivo califica a dos o más sustantivos coordinados y va pospuesto a ellos, lo más recomendable es que el adjetivo vaya en plural y en masculino, si los sustantivos son de distinto género: «Tiene el pelo y la barba enmarañados» (Matos Noche [Cuba 2002]); «Apareció [...] vestida con traje y mantilla blancos» (Hernández Secreter [Esp. 1995]). Si concordase solo con el último de los sustantivos, se generarían casos de ambigüedad, pues podría interpretarse que el adjetivo únicamente se refiere al más cercano: vestida con traje y mantilla blanca. [Adjetivo pospuesto a varios sustantivos, concordancia, RAE](https://%27Adjetivo%20pospuesto%20a%20varios%20sustantivos%27%20-%20concordancia%20-%20RAE%5D)

Por lo tanto:

> Persona competente en el uso de ordenador y con excelentes capacidades de {[[comunicación] y [expresión]] [tanto **escritas** como **verbales**]}.

> Persona competente en el uso de ordenador y con excelentes capacidades de {[comunicación] y [expresión tanto **escrita** como **verbal**]}.

Ambas frases son correctas pero la segunda es más ambigua, ya que como podés ver hay una posible interpretación por la que *escrita* y *verbal* sólo estarían afectando a *expresión*. Pero creo que  tiene más sentido que ambos adjetivos afecten a ambos sustantivos y por lo tanto deberían ir en plural. De nuevo, en este ejemplo no hay mucha diferencia y cualquiera de las dos se entiende en un sentido 'extragramatical'; pero siempre es mejor evitar la ambigüedad gramatical porque a veces puede traer confusión.

Answer (score 0):

*"Escrita"* y *"verbal"*, ambas hacen referencia a las capacidades, por tanto deben ir acordes con esta. Si *capacidad* va en singular, los adjetivos también y lo mismo sucede con el plural.

> ...con excelentes **capacidades** de comunicación y (*capacidades de*) expresión tanto **escritas** como **verbales**

> ...con excelente **capacidad** de comunicación y (*capacidad de*) expresión tanto **escrita** como **verbal**

*"Escrita"* y *"verbal"* no tienen relación directa en número con *"comunicación"* y *"expresión"* sino con la "capacidad de".

Si "limpias" la frase, los adjetivos van acorde al número del sustantivo:

> Con **capacidad escrita y verbal**

> Con **capacidades escritas y verbales**

Distinto el caso de sustantivos en ambas partes:

> Con **capacidad** de comunicación y expresión tanto en **escritura** como en **locución**

> Con **capacidades** de comunicación y expresión tanto en **escritura** como en **locución**